# Attributes of attributes : point.coord, point.coord.x and point.coord.y

Tags: python

I don't know exactly how to formulate it, but I want to create a class `Point` with which the coordinates of a point can be accessed both as a tuple and individually, as follows:

```
point.coord
# tuple (x,y)

point.coord.x
point.coord.y
# coordinates x and y
```

Do I necessarily have to declare a method `point.coord()`, or is there such a thing as attributes of attributes? And, for other purposes, what about longer embedded attributes (`object.attr1.attr2.attr3`)?

Comment: "is there such a thing as attributes of attributes?" - yes. "what about longer embedded attributes (`object.attr1.attr2.attr3`)?" - you can have as many attributes as you please. However, an ordinary tuple like `(5, 6)` doesn't have the `x` or `y` attributes - you'll have to design your own class for that

Comment: To add on to what @ForceBru said. You would access those elements as `point.coord[0]` and `point.coord[1]`. If you want to be able to do something like `point.coord.x` without writing a whole class checkout Python's [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Coord(tuple):
    def __init__(self, points):
        self.x, self.y = points

class Point:
    def __init__(self, *points):
        self.coord = Coord(points)


point = Point(1, 2)

print(point.coord)
print(point.coord.x)
print(point.coord.y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit of a hack for you. If you inherit from `tuple` you can have the return type still be a `tuple`, then you just need a wrapper for `Point` and a way to access the properties of the `tuple`. That could be done through either a `namedtuple` or just like this:

```py
In [52]: class Coord(tuple):
    ...:     def __init__(self, xy):
    ...:         super().__init__()
    ...:         x, y = xy
    ...:         self._x = x
    ...:         self._y = y
    ...:     @property
    ...:     def x(self):
    ...:         return self._x
    ...:     @property
    ...:     def y(self):
    ...:         return self._y
    ...:

In [53]: class Point:
    ...:     def __init__(self, coord: Coord):
    ...:         self.coord = coord
    ...:

In [54]: p = Point(Coord((5,12)))

In [55]: p.coord
Out[55]: (5, 12)

In [56]: p.coord.x
Out[56]: 5

In [57]: p.coord.y
Out[57]: 12
```